# Return value wrapped around anonymous function in javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, anonymous-function

Could someone explain to me what's wrong with `checkX()`'s scope? What I'm suspecting that's wrong is the anonymous function somehow blocks it but I'm not sure how to bypass that.

```
storage = chrome.storage;

function checkX(){
    var x = false;

    storage.sync.get(function(data){
        if(data.x == true){
                x = true;
                console.log(x); // << x : true
        }
    });

            console.log(x); // << x : false
    return x;
}
```

console.log result order:

```
x : false
x : true
```

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive : x != X

Comment: After the edit, this seems to be the typical asynchronous issue.

Comment: I added some information about storage.sync in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things that might -and probably will- throw you:

1. JavaScript is case-Sensitive
2. the `get` method, as used by you is *asynchronous*, your IIFE returns prior to the passed callback function is being executed, so it'll return the value of `x` before the callback changes it anyhow.

*Edit:*
The `get` method is just a getter, fair enough, however there is a major difference between `chrome.storage.sync.get`, which gets the data using google sync, and `chrome.storage.local.get`, which is (almost) the same thing as using the `localStorage` object, with the added benefits of events. At least, that's what [Google's docs](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage.html) are telling me at first glance?

*From the comments below:*
The issue here is how and when JS calls the callback function. Even though the getter the OP uses is getting *local* data, the IIFE has to return first, before JS, being single threaded, can call the callback. That's why the IIFE returns `false`.

Comment: I accidentally capitalized X, thats not the actual issue. I also added some information about storage.sync in my question

Comment: @AdonisK.: Well than, the added info actually confirms that the issue is the asynchronous character of the `get` method, as I said in my second point: the IIFE is invoked, calls the get method, and returns, when the `get` method receives an answer, it calls the callback function. By that time, the IIFE has long since returned...

Comment: but the `get` function is just a getter function, it doesn't involve the HTTP GET method.

Comment: @AdonisK.: You're using `sync.get`, that getter uses google sync, you should use `local.get`... [read the docs](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage.html), but because of your using a callback, you might have to use a setTimeout call to return the correct value all the same

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me debug this.
sync's storage is synced from the computer to the Google sync, not the other way around (at least in this occasion) so it shouldn't take any time to load that value. The value is still stored locally.
I'm most certainly sure the issue with that `if(data.x == true){x = true;}` is creating another local variable called `x` for the anonymous function's scope so it doesn't pass the data to the x variable inside `getX()`

Comment: @AdonisK.: That doesn't matter, you call a function, and pass a callback to it as an argument. Since JS is _single threaded_, that callback will be moved to the back of the queue, prior to it being called! the IIFE just __HAS__ to return first. A _callback_ is basically saying _Do this, when I call-you-back. For now, I'm going to finish this, first_ Where the data is coming from is completely irrelevant. That's why, in a callback, the called context (the `this` reference) will point to the global object, it's called in some other time, some other place!

Comment: Check the question's code again, i added 2 `console.logs` to show you how there is no issue with sync.get

Comment: @AdonisK. I wasn't talking about `sync.get` I'm talking about _how JS deals with callbacks_. The get method is called in the IIFE's scope, so it's called immediatly. A callback is a function call that is called _as soon as possible_, but since JS is single threaded, and the IIFE is yet to return, the callback _has to wait it's turn_. What part of this is unclear? JS can't call _a callback that is passed to another function that is called witin another function prior to the functions that are called have returned_. Does it log `true` and then `false`, or the other way around?

Comment: I see, its first false and then true.
Thanks for clearing that up, I had no idea it worked that way.

I will need to do some study on IIFE then and understand the way it works i guess so i can fix my issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is case sensitive. What you are doing is creating a global variable `x` which is `true`, while the local variable `X` remains `false`.

```
storage = chrome.storage;

function checkX(){
    var X = false;

    storage.sync.get(function(data){
        if(data.x == true){
            x = true;  <--- global variable
        }
    });

    return x;
}
```

---

Another issue would be if the `storage.sync.get` runs async from the "checkX", which would mean that first you return x and only later on (after you have returned it) will your function be executed. This will happen for sure if storage.sync.get is an ajax call.

Comment: I accidentally capitalized X, thats not the actual issue. I also added some information about storage.sync in my question